# Spring Integeration SFTP outbound gateway mget -R issue

Tags: java, spring-integration

we are trying to connect to SFTP server using spring integration [SFTP outbound-gateway]  to download all files with the following directory expression '/*/*/foo/' . unfortunately we are getting different exceptions :

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to list files; nested exception is 2: No such file
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:103)
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.listFilesInRemoteDir(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:582)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.ls(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:551)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.mGetWithRecursion(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:753)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.mGet(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:713)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway$3.doInSession(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:455)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway$3.doInSession(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:451)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:334)
... 33 more
    Caused by: 2: No such file
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2833)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2185)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2202)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1566)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1527)
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:91)
... 41 more
```

we are using the following :

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="sftpFactory" request-channel="download"
        command="mget" command-options="-R" expression="'/*/*/foo/'" remote-file-separator="/" 
        local-directory-expression="'${local.dir}'+ #remoteDirectory" reply-channel="outputChannel"
        auto-create-local-directory="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only simple wildcards are supported, such as `/foo/*` - meaning fetch recursively from `/foo` - the `*` is actually not needed in this case, `/foo/` will do the same thing.

But, there's no way to wild-card higher level directories.

Depending on how complex your tree is, you might be able to use a custom filter instead - the filter is invoked during each recursion (where each directory is listed, filter applied, then files fetched).